# Is $\Sigma^\infty_+ O(n)^\vee$, the Spanier-Whitehead dual of the orthogonal group, an $A_\infty$-ring spectrum?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, infinity-categories, spanier-whitehead-duality

Recently, [Ching and Salvatore](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.03878) have proven that the $E_n$ operad is Koszul self dual. While thinking about the analogous question for the framed $E_n$ operad, I realized there is an obvious first question: does the spectrum $\Sigma^\infty_+ O(n)^\vee$ have an $A_\infty$-structure? Perhaps worth noting, since $\Sigma^\infty_+ O(n)$ is self dual, it suffices to show $\Sigma^{-n(n-1)/2}_+ O(n)$ has an $A_\infty$ structure.

Edit: I realized this question is very basic; the Spanier-Whitehead dual of any space is canonically $E_\infty$ via the diagonal.

Comment: Isn't it a split square zero extension of the sphere?

Comment: @TimCampion I don't know what that actually means. Does the multiplication from dualizing $O(n) \times O(n) \xrightarrow{\mu \wedge 1} O(n) \times O(n)$ and composing one of the factors with $O(n)_+ ^\vee \rightarrow S^0$?

Comment: I just mean that $\Sigma^\infty_+ O(n)^\vee = \mathbb S \oplus \Sigma^\infty O(n)^\vee$. Since $\Sigma^\infty O(n)^\vee$ is a $\mathbb S$-bimodule, there's an algebra structure on $\mathbb S \oplus \Sigma^\infty O(n)^\vee$ where the multiplication is zero on $\Sigma^\infty O(n)^\vee \otimes \Sigma^\infty O(n)^\vee$. (so no, the multiplication on $O(n)$ is not involved here)

Comment: Ching and Salvatore's proof is O(n) equivariant- doesn't that imply the result for all the 'framed' variants?

Comment: @DylanWilson Well there is not even a definition yet of the Koszul dual of an unreduced operad that coincides with Ching and Salvatore's for reduced operads (as far as I know).

Comment: It was pointed out to me there is a proposed definition of Koszul duals for certain unreduced operads due to Benjamin Ward (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.00970.pdf). Though since it involves classifying spaces for $O(n)$ in the case of the framed disks operad there can't be a self duality result on the nose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question as stated probably requires clarification. If

$X$ is a space, then the S-dual $D_+(X)$ (i.e., functions from $X_+$ to the sphere) is always an $E_\infty$-ring spectrum. In particular, it will also be an $A_\infty$-ring.

Perhaps what is being asked is whether $D_+(G)$ is an **$A_\infty$-coalgebra** when $G$ is a topological group. The answer is yes, because $G$ is an $A_\infty$-space.